# git show command yields no results

Tags: git, show

Trying to understand this:

```
PS C:\Users\BRITTG2\source\repos\tbsm.canoe.core (feature/bau-1057)
> git ls-files | sls Filtered

Projects/TBSM.Canoe.Core/TBSM.Canoe.Core.Common/TBSM.Canoe.Core.Common.Domain/Certificates/FilteredCertificates.cs
```

Why does git show not display the blob and also not give an error?

```
PS C:\Users\BRITTG2\source\repos\tbsm.canoe.core (feature/bau-1057)
> git show Projects/TBSM.Canoe.Core/TBSM.Canoe.Core.Common/TBSM.Canoe.Core.Common.Domain/Certificates/FilteredCertificates.cs

PS C:\Users\BRITTG2\source\repos\tbsm.canoe.core (feature/bau-1057)
>
```

for comparison

```
    > cat Projects/TBSM.Canoe.Core/TBSM.Canoe.Core.Common/TBSM.Canoe.Core.Common.Domain/Certificates/FilteredCertificates.cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
etc.
```

Update:

the first answer below works:

```
git show HEAD:yourfile
```

Is there a way to specify wildcards in the show command so that I can show the file without a full  (and possibly long) path?

Comment: @RomainValeri er, part of git core? git help show?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git show yourfile` is equivalent to `git show HEAD -- yourfile` and will try to find the changes to the file in the current commit. If the file was not modified in that commit, nothing will be shown.

To instead show the content of a file as it was at a given revision:

```
git show HEAD:yourfile
```

Comment: so this form: `git show yourfile` is similar to `git diff yourfile`?  good to know!